# How do you delete a sprint in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services)

Tags: azure-devops, agile, sprint

Under "Work" in VSTS, I created some test sprints. Now I would like to remove them. How do you delete sprints?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Click Project Settings -> Work, you will be able to delete the sprints.
[image]

For New Navigation:
[image]